# When storing doubles in array they are getting messed up

Tags: c++, arrays, double

hello I have an array of 25 doubles in a c++ program. When I am putting doubles into an array they look like this 1.29839, and then when I try to access this number in the array it looks like this 4.45053e-317. I am kind of newb and really lost. If anybody has any idea why this would be happening your help would be greatly appreciated.

Here Is The code:

```
int main()
{
    double los[25];
    ifstream html;
    html.open("tmp");
    int count = 0;
    while(html.good())
    {
        //cout << "in\n" ;
        string line;
        getline(html, line);
        if(line.length() > 11)
        {
            string tmp = line.substr(10);
            if(tmp.length() > 3)
            {
                string cmp = tmp.substr(2,2);
                if(cmp == "lo")
                {
                    //cout << "\n" << tmp << "\n";
                    double curr = atof(tmp.substr(13).c_str());
                    los[count] == curr;
                    cout << curr << "\n";
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << count << "\n";
    for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
    {
        double curr = los[i];
        cout << curr << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code

Comment: please post the code here that you are trying out

Comment: Probably some undefined behaviour.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your program. Check the array at every step and figure out the point at which it changes. The answer should be obvious, and if it isn't you'll have a much better question.

Comment: `los[count] == curr;`

Comment: OOO haha ooops that answers it thank you

Comment: @user315052, that's funny - usually that typo occurs the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not assigning anything into your array.  The line

```
los[count] == curr;
```

is just evaluating whether they are equal, and not storing the result anywhere, thus doing nothing.  Change that to use just a single `=`.

To avoid some of these issues, always compile with warnings enabled (`-W -Wall` is a good place to start).  You would have got a warning saying something about the line doing nothing, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

Change `los[count] == curr;` to `los[count] = curr;`

Currently, the line does not work like an assignment.